# ActionResult not calling to partialView when calls from Ajax hit in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to call partial view after calling ActionResult with ajax hit and render partial view data into main view. But when calling to ActionResult, its calling perfectly but not calling to Partial view and returning error message in ajax.
Ajax method is as:

```
function postComment() {
    var comment = $("#addComment").val();
    var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    var title = pathname[pathname.length - 1];
    alert(comment);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        url: "/Blogger/PostComment",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'comment': comment, "title": title ,"type":"Blogs"}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#divAnswerSchemeContainer1").html(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Action Result is:

```
public ActionResult PostComment(string comment, string title, string type) {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_partialShowComments", db.SocialMediaComments.ToList());
        }
```

And the partial view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataModel.SocialMediaComment>

<div id="divAnswerSchemeContainer1">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.Comment
    @item.CreatedDate
    @item.BlogeName
}
</div>
```

Action result calling fine with ajax but partial view not hitting well and returning error message from ajax.

Browser console showing error message:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:6767/Blogger/PostComment"
```

Comment: step through your code and see where exactly is the error occurring and what the exact error is.

Comment: where is db defined? Put a break point in the PostComment action to see the actual error.

Comment: Also, I think you don't need this contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Change dataType to json.  It won't map properly since you are specifying html data posting but sending it as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to create viewmodel.

```
 public class Post{
    public string comment {get;set;}
    public string title {get;set;}
    public string type {get;set;}
 }
```

you action controller be like.

```
public ActionResult PostComment(Post post) {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_partialShowComments", db.SocialMediaComments.ToList());
    }
```